# Is it possible to create a Tags style field?

Tags: wordpress, podscms

Is it possible, with Pods or something else dedicated to Wordpress, to create a tags style field as there is when writing a post in Stackoverflow or Wordpress ?

The goal is to create a form on a page and allow a user to enter their own tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is a custom taxonomy. Tags is an example of a non-hierarchical taxonomy. Categories is an example of a hierarchical taxonomy. Pods will allow you to easily add a custom taxonomy. Here is documentation on the process: https://github.com/pods-framework/pods-code-library/blob/master/learn/content-types/create-taxonomy.md

You can also add a custom taxonomy manually. I recommend using the taxonomy generator provided by GenerateWP:
http://generatewp.com/taxonomy/